# Allow only specific emails to register in Rails app (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise to authenticate and register users in my Rails app. However, I only want users who have an email with a specific ending to be able to sign up and access it (let's say @xyz.com). What do I need to do to reflect that?

Comment: Are you saying you have a fixed set of domains that you'd allow emails for? Or are you saying you only want invited users allowed? For the latter, It would be easy enough to create an "invites" table and only allow emails which have been invited to sign up. For the latter, you could use a regex. Either way, you'd likely be overriding the devise controller sign up method. For overriding, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller.

Comment: Allow only specific domain names to register in Rails App (Devise gem) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009709/1711149

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict users access after the registration use before_filter:

```
before_filter :verify_email

private

def verify_email
  (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.email.include?('@xyz.com')
end
```

Edit: if you want to restrict registration you could just do a form validation to check whether the email matches your pattern

Comment: Where should I add that?

Comment: To the controller in which you want to restrict the access. If it's app-wide, then application_controller.rb

Comment: This doesn't look like it works. If the email doesn't have that ending, I don't even want the user to be able to sign up in the first place.

Comment: @MPorto If thats the case, then add a validation for the email in the model. Something like `validates :email, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@xyz\.com\z/, message: "must be a xyz.com account" }`

Answer (score 0):

Devise offers a way to validate email addresses.
Take a look to the documentation:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable