# Controllers inside Rails engines (gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I'm learning how to build a Rails gem (engine, to be more specific). I first read some existing open source code like Devise, but I can't understand the controllers inside it. In `app/controllers` there is _devise_controller.rb_ with module hierarchy

```
 class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
```

but in `lib/devise/controllers/` there are also many controllers with module hierarchy

```
module Devise 
  module Controllers
```

what's the difference between these controllers (like which is called when I get "users/sign_up")? Can someone who has more experience using Devise explain?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the Devise controllers are inside their own module to not pollute the global namespace. Check for example the case in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553561/1744702) where the new class is based on Devise's *RegistrationController*

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

if it weren't inside the *Devise* the name *RegistrationsController* would already be taken.

The controllers under `app/controllers/devise` are the actual controllers that the router redirects requests to. The ones under `lib/devise/controllers` are helpers for the controllers and thus are in module Devise::Controllers for convenience.

When `users/sign_up` is called, it is routed to _registrations_controller.rb:6_. This isn't done the normal way via *routes.rb* probably because Devise needs to adjust the URLs per application since you don't always use *users* as the path. Instead is done by `devise/rails/routes.rb` which is where the line

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
```

from actual applications *routes.rb* takes to.

Answer (score 1):

I've included controllers in a [gem I wrote some time back](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/tree/master/app/controllers/exception_handler).

One of the main reasons for using the namespace is because your entire gem should be under the duress of a single module:

```
#lib/exception_handler.rb
module ExceptionHandler

    #Exception Handler
    class Exceptions < Rails::Engine
```

This means that if you're calling a *controller* from within the gem (which is meant to be self-contained), you'll generally have to invoke it **inside** the module:

```
ExceptionHandler::ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
```

--

In the sense of Devise, it makes sense for them to include their controllers in a namespace for two reasons:

- It permits them to call their controllers from within their module
- They are able to include the controllers without the need of external dependencies

> which is called when I get "users/sign_up"

The devise controllers can be broken down by the [*routes* Devise sets](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for):

```
 new_user_session     GET       /users/sign_in       {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"new"}
 user_session         POST      /users/sign_in       {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"create"}
 destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out       {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"destroy"}
```

These are just routes for the `sessions` controller (which handles login etc).

There are other routes including `registrations` etc.

The key here is to understand that Devise has to work "out of the box" -- otherwise most people wouldn't use it. It achieves this by self-containing its controllers, ensuring that, as `sanfor` recommended, they are not conflicted.

If you have more specific requests, I'll gladly answer them for you.