# Why is this attribute lost before it's evaluated in this rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I am using devise and have overridden the registrations controller to allow a user to be "soft-deleted" following the instructions here: [devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account).

I've put some `puts` commands through my code to follow the test and my rspec result looks like this:

```
    10:00:30 - INFO - Running: spec/controllers/users/registrations_controller_spec.rb
    ..
>   BEFORE: id:2, deleted_at:
>    -- model: id:2, deleted_at:2016-12-08 15:00:35 UTC
>    -- controller: id:2, deleted_at:2016-12-08 15:00:35 UTC
>   AFTER: id:2, deleted_at:
    F..

    Failures:

      1) Users::RegistrationsController GET #destroy sets 'deleted_at' date for user
         Failure/Error: expect(user.deleted_at).to_not be_nil

           expected: not nil
                got: nil
         # ./spec/controllers/users/registrations_controller_spec.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 0.37438 seconds (files took 3.7 seconds to load)
    5 examples, 1 failure
```

As the `puts` show, my user starts out with the `deleted_at` field set to null.  The model sets `deleted_at` to the current time and the controller confirms that the date is set, but by the time I get to my `expect()` statement in my test `user.deleted_at` is back to `nil`.  This appears to be a problem with my test because the application functions properly.

**/spec/controllers/users/registrations_controller_spec.rb**

```
  require 'rails_helper'
  require 'factory_girl_rails'

  RSpec.describe Users::RegistrationsController, type: :controller do    
     include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

     describe "GET #destroy" do

        it "sets 'deleted_at' date for user" do
          request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

          # sign-in user
          user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_for_account_update)
          sign_in(user, scope: :user) # note: does not verify correct password

          # soft-delete user
          puts "BEFORE: id:#{user.id}, deleted_at:#{user.deleted_at}"
          delete :destroy, {:id => user.id}
          puts "AFTER: id:#{user.id}, deleted_at:#{user.deleted_at}"

          expect(user.deleted_at).to_not be_nil
        end
     end
  end
```

**/spec/factories/user.rb**

```
require 'ffaker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    @pass = "password"

    name FFaker::Name.name
    email { |me| "#{name.to_s.gsub(/\s/,'.')}_#{rand(1000).to_s}@testing.com" }
    password @pass

    factory :user_for_account_update do
      password_confirmation @pass
      confirmed_at Date.today
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/models/user.rb**

```
  ...

  # instead of deleting, indicate the user requested a delete & timestamp it
  def soft_delete
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
    puts " -- model: id:#{id}, deleted_at:#{deleted_at.to_s}"
  end

  ...
```

**/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
# This class overrides devise's registration controller.  All
# other devise actions remain (I believe) handled as usual by 
# devise.  I think it is the route that does that by specifying
# this controller specifically for the purpose of registrations
#
# see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # SOFT DELETE /resource
  # Follows devise guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account
  def destroy
    resource.soft_delete
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_flashing_format?
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
    puts " -- controller: id:#{resource.id}, deleted_at:#{resource.deleted_at}"
  end

  protected

  # we have to explicitly permit params in overridden controllers like this
  # see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to do `user.reload` to get updated info from DB?

Comment: I did not know about that (I'm very new to rails, obviously).  Makes perfect sense and solves the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `user` that was created before controller action so it has cached values (including `deleted_at`).

You can use `user.reload` to get updated attributes from DB