# How do I access current user object in Devise sign up controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise on Rails.

I want to set some values for the user object variable in the sign up controller create action. for that I want to access the user object

My use case is set the plan_id at sign_up; 
the url is example.com/users/sign_up?plan_id=1

I want to set that plan_id to the user object which was just created..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override devise registrations controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553561/6548745), override the controller and set routes.
Then in the `create` action,

```
def create
  super do |resource|
    resource.update_attribute(:plan_id, params[:plan_id])
  end
end
```