# Ruby on Rails how do I create a has_one dependency on the creation of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am attempting to create an association between

```
class User 
  has_one :user_profile
end

class UserProfile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to create the ability to create the association when the user is created.

I have attempted things in the User Model like

```
   before_create :build_profile

   private
   def build_profile
     default_pararms = { some_key: value}
     @profile = self.create_user_pofile!(default_params)
   end
```

---- stack is returning ----

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 136ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-31 01:56:40 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):

activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in `controller_class_for'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:78:in `controller_class'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `controller'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error stack trace

Comment: Question doesn't contain enough information to help you out.

Comment: Error is a routing error and indicates you don't have routes setup for `users`.  You need in your routes.rb file `resources :users` and obviously also `app/controllers/userss_controller.rb` needs to be set up.

Comment: you can use `nested_attribute` feature of rails to overcome all headache

Comment: you just need to put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile` inside `user` model and use fields for inside user form

Comment: I am using Devise for my user model. so it handles controllers is there a way I could patch this?

Comment: @CoreyGibson Yes, you can override devise controllers. Take a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/3546289/1154044