# Custom field for f.select - Allowing user to type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a user (`candidate`) to select his skills (like python, rails, node..) while he is signing up.

I know I can use the following:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select(:skill, [['Python', 'Python'],
                                  ['Java', 'Java'],
                                  ['Rails', 'Rails'],
                                 ],
                                   { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }
                                 ) %>
```

**BUT**

What if I want the user to add a custom field?

Imagine the user has also the skill `Javascript`. As it is now, he cannot selected it.

How can I allow him to add a custom field in the `f.select`?

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "candidates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "skill"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_candidates_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_candidates_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

**I tried**

```
<head>
  <script>$( "#user_organization_name" ).keypress(function() {
    $('#custom_org_id_select_menu').removeClass();
});</script>
</head>

<h2>Sign up for candidates</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                placehoder: "name@gmail.com",
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
    <%= f.input :password,
                required: true,
                hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" },
                placeholder: "xYui6578Z!"%>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                required: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" },
                placeholder: "Repeat above password"%>
<div id="custom_org_id_select_menu">
        <%= f.select(:skill, [['Python', 'Python'],
                                  ['Java', 'Java'],
                                  ['Rails', 'Rails'],
                                 ],
                                   { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }
                                 ) %>
 </div>

  <div id="custom_org_id hide">
    <%= f.input :skill, label: "Others" %>
  </div>
```

It does work, but if the users writes something in `other` and selects something from the list (python, java etc), only what the user writes in `other` is sent via the params.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic param for other skill and use it in the create action, like:

```html
<div id="custom_org_id_select_menu">
  <%= f.select(:skill, [['Python', 'Python'], ['Java', 'Java'], ['Rails', 'Rails']],{ :multiple => true, :size => 5 }) %>
</div>

<div id="custom_org_id hide">
  <label>Others</label>
  <input name="other_skill" />
</div>
```

```rb
def create
  if params[:other_skill].present?
    # do something with the params[:other_skill] value
  end
  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Being `candidate` created visa devise, I do not have a specific controller for it. Should I create a controller for `candidate`?

Comment: @Prova12 you can override the devise's registration controller (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553561/9541423))