# How to specify what controllers should be used when creating routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes, registration

I'm creating a Rails app and I'm trying to do not use Devise to handle my registrations & sessions related to my `User` model but I'm running into an issue.

I'd like to have specific routes like that:

- http://localhost:3000/users/registrations/new
- http://localhost:3000/users/sessions/new

I tried several solution but none is working, last try was those lines of code:

```
get "users/registrations/new", to: "registrations#new", controller: "users/registrations", as: :new_registration
get "users/sessions/new", to: "sessions#new", controller: "users/sessions", as: :new_session
```

But I got the following error: `uninitialized constant RegistrationsController`

My `registrations_controller` and my `sessions_controller` are in the following path: app/controllers/users/

Is anyone knows how I could handle that? Should I use `resources` or a `namespace`? I already tried those solutions but I'm facing the same issue all the time...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Comment: Not really because I'm not using Devise in my app. But thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`to: "namespace/name_of_controller#action"`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), in your case

```rb
get "users/registrations/new", to: "users/registrations#new", as: :new_registration
get "users/sessions/new", to: "users/sessions#new", as: :new_session
```

Another way, and more "Rails-y", is to use `namespace`

```rb
namespace :users do
  resources :registrations, only: [:new] # If you want only the new action
  # ...
end
```