# Mass assignment warning when using nested attributes with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-attributes

I'm having trouble with nested attributes and Devise.  A similar issue to [How do I use nested attributes with the devise model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544265/how-do-i-use-nested-attributes-with-the-devise-model).
As far as I can tell I've got everything set up as recommended here:
[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller/4527049#4527049)

I've set up the associations for Users and Subscriptions, I have `"accepts_nested_attributes_for"`, and included the `:subscriptions_attributes` in `attr_accessible`, but I get a warning from the Devise controller.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
    has_many :subscriptions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :subscriptions_attributes    
    ... 
end
```

--

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :chargify_subscription_id, :chargify_product_handle
  attr_accessible :user_id, :chargify_subscription_id, :chargify_product_handle
  ... 
end
```

devise/registrations/new.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <p><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>
    ...

    <%= f.fields_for :subscription do |s| %>
        <p><%= s.label :chargify_subscription_id %><br />
          <%= s.text_field :chargify_subscription_id %></p>
            ...
```

I'm getting the following warning:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat May 14 12:38:49 -0700 2011
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign up", "authenticity_token"=>"wNZhZgIhYm9CpZfhvDiRBqaJseoO8QvR0Mk9VIybhcI=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",        "last_name"=>"9", "subscription"=>{"chargify_product_handle"=>"medium", "chargify_subscription_id"=>"123"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"9", "email"=>"99@99.     com"}}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: subscription
```

I've tried using `subscription_attributes` (singular) in `attr_accessible` but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `attr_accessible :subscription`?

Comment: @ecoologic - that gives an `unknown attribute: subscription` error in `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`.  Also tried `attr_accessible :subscriptions` but get my original error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a has_many association between your User and Subscription model, I believe you need to specify `fields_for :subscriptions` rather than `fields_for :subscription`.

```
<%= f.fields_for :subscriptions do |s| %>
    <p><%= s.label :chargify_subscription_id %><br />
      <%= s.text_field :chargify_subscription_id %></p>
        ...
```

The attributes within the fields_for scope will then be passed using the subscriptions_attributes parameter, which should work since you have `attr_accessible :subscriptions_attributes`.

For more examples of nested has_many association forms, check out the 'Nested Attributes Examples' section (one-to-many) of the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: Yes this is it, then using `accept_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions` you don't even need to do check for `@user.save` to save `@subscriptions` in your controller!

Comment: Thanks - that did it. I originally thought `fields_for :subscriptions` was wrong because the subscriptions form fields were not getting rendered. However that was because `subscriptions` was not initialized by Devise::RegistrationsController.  As suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller/4527049#4527049, we can build resource.subscriptions in the view.  However I think that belongs in the controller, and now I'm having a problem with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005932/nested-model-not-available-in-devise-views.