# Nested model not available in Devise views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-forms

I'm having a problem with associations not being available in my views.

My models are:

```
:user has_many :subscriptions
:subscription belongs_to :user
```

I'm using Devise to manage authentication etc. for Users

What I'd like to do: when creating a new user in the registration process, I also want to also create a subscription for that user.
Since `Devise::RegistrationsController#new` by default does not initialize an associated subscription, I've created my own `RegistrationsController`:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    resource.subscriptions.build
    logger.debug resource.subscriptions.inspect
  end
end
```

The debug statement there confirms that a `Subscription` object is successfully created:

```
[#<Subscription id: nil, user_id: nil, chargify_subscription_id: nil, chargify_product_handle: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

The problem: in the view, `resource.subscriptions` does not exist.
If I inspect `resource` in the view, I get a `User` object that includes all of its own attributes but no associations (it should have an associated `subscriptions`)

`debug(resource)` gives the following:

```
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  name:
  encrypted_password: ""
  created_at:
  updated_at:
  last_sign_in_ip:
  last_sign_in_at:
  sign_in_count: 0      last_name:
  current_sign_in_ip:
  reset_password_token:
  current_sign_in_at:
  remember_created_at:
  reset_password_sent_at:
  chargify_customer_reference:
  first_name:
  email: ""
attributes_cache: {}

changed_attributes: {}

destroyed: false
marked_for_destruction: false
new_record: true
previously_changed: {}

readonly: false
```

Is there something I'm missing, or perhaps is there something strange about the `resource` mechanism used by Devise that prevents associations from being available in the    view?

Thanks!

Edit:
If I just add `resource.subscriptions.build` in my view before rending the form, that works fine.  But I think that kind of logic belongs in the controller and not the view, and I'd like to know what's keeping me from being able to put it there.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is really late, but I found that if I override the entire controller action "new" (instead of delegating some of it to the parent with "super"), then I can build the resource properly. The reason is because "super" renders the view before handing control back to your custom controller method. Long story short...

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    resource = build_resource({})  # as found in Devise::RegistrationsController
    resource.subscriptions.build
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new } # also from Devise
  end
end
```

Should work nicely...at least it did for me. Your code got me started on the right track anyway.